# Are complaints to hospital administration PHI under HIPAA's Privacy Rule

Tags: united-states, privacy, hipaa

Paul has heart surgery. While he's recovering, staff is constantly distracted by their phones and fails to check in on him at required intervals, administer medication on time, and provide medically recommended therapy.

Before he checks out, Paul sees that the hospital's website has a form for making a complaint to hospital administration. Paul fills it out and notes all the information above.

The hospital's CEO reads the form, disciplines all the staff identified, and takes no further action with it.

To what extent is the form covered by HIPAA's Privacy Rule?

I'm looking for answers supported by law addressing similar facts.

Answer (score 4):

PHI is health information that is individually identifiable. Any record, even a post-it note, can be PHI.

In this case, the complaint form is PHI if it contains the patient's name or other identifier along with the details of treatment.

When PHI is held by a covered entity, including the hospital CEO, it is protected by HIPAA privacy regulations.

Comment: But is the complaint form "health information"? Is the context in which the information relayed relevant? In other words, does it matter that Paul disclosed this information to complain about a business transaction with the hospital, as opposed to disclosing it for the purposes of obtaining medical treatment?

Comment: It's health information if it contains details of treatment. The reason for recording the information is irrelevant.

Comment: Are you able to point to any law supporting this interpretation?

Comment: @bdb484  Assuming the complaint contained PHI, the Privacy Rules contain numerous provisions for authorizing further disclosure related to handling complaints. See, e.g., 45 CFR s. § 164.512 "Uses and disclosures for which an authorization or opportunity to agree or object is not required," particularly, (d) "Standard: Uses and disclosures for health oversight activities."

Comment: @bdb484 Per 45 CFR 160.103

*Health information means any information …  whether oral or recorded in any form or medium, that: 

(1) Is created or received by a health care provider …  ; and 

(2) Relates to the past, present, or future physical or mental health or condition of an individual; the provision of health care to an individual; or the past, present, or future payment for the provision of health care to an individual. 

*Individually identifiable health information is information that is a subset of health information, including demographic information … 
[edited for space]

Comment: But "health information" isn't always *protected* health information, is it? I guess what I'm really asking is whether there is any law addressing the type of scenario I'm looking for.

Comment: @bdb484 Protected health information is also defined in 45 CFR 160.103. PHI basically means individually identifiable health information with these exceptions: 
"(i) In education records covered by the Family Educational Rights and Privacy Act, as amended, 20 U.S.C. 1232g; 
(ii) In records described at 20 U.S.C. 1232g(a)(4)(B)(iv); 
(iii) In employment records held by a covered entity in its role as employer; and 
(iv) Regarding a person who has been deceased for more than 50 years." The law does not provide any other exceptions, so the complaint is PHI if it meets the previous criteria.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that definition and the part about records held "in its role as employer." If that complaint was stuck in a personnel file as part of the employee's discipline, is it still PHI?

Comment: That exception is meant for health information regarding an employee. For example, normally pregnancy status is PHI. But if an employee requests maternity leave then the request in her employment records is not PHI, even if the employer is a covered entity. 

Putting PHI where it doesn't belong is a HIPAA violation. The original complaint in your example cannot go into an employee file, just as it cannot be left in a cafeteria. 

Hospitals routinely scrub identifiers from medical records when performing QA. After this, a complaint is no longer protected and can go into an employee file.